# C++ Run error with wild characters; no compile and build errors

Tags: c++, build, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I am using Code::Blocks to write this C++ program, but everytime I do a 3rd Insert on the Link List, and when I use the Display option to check my work, I get a strange error.  I have encountered no build errors.  Please help check and advise when you have the chance, thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

typedef struct student
{
    string name;
    int quiz1, quiz2, quiz3;
    struct student *nxt;
} STUDENT;

class studentsStruct
{
private:
    STUDENT *S; //Header of the Student List
public:
    void init();
    void add(string n, int a, int b, int c);
    void del(string n);
    void update(string n);
    void save();
    void retrieve();
    void display();
};

int menu();
int updatemenu();
float round2(float x); // function to round the average and limit to 2 decimal points

int main()
{
    studentsStruct ars;
    string nm;
    int a, b, c;

    ars.init();     // Initialize the S Header of the Student List
    ars.retrieve(); // Check if the "studentsdb.txt" is available and load the data as needed

    while (1)
    {
        switch (menu())
        {
        case 1:
            system("cls");
            cout << "Insert Mode" << endl;
            cout << "Name: ";
            cin >> nm;
            cout << "Input Quiz 1: ";
            cin >> a;
            cout << "Input Quiz 2: ";
            cin >> b;
            cout << "Input Quiz 3: ";
            cin >> c;
            ars.add(nm, a, b, c);
            break;
        case 2:
            system("cls");
            cout << "Update Mode" << endl;
            cout << "Input Students Name: ";
            cin >> nm;
            ars.update(nm);
            break;
        case 3:
            system("cls");
            cout << "Delete Mode" << endl;
            cout << "Enter Name: ";
            cin >> nm;
            ars.del(nm);
            break;
        case 4:
            ars.display();
            break;
        case 5:
            ars.save();
            exit(0);
        default:
            cout << "1 to 5 only. ";
            system("pause");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void studentsStruct::init()
{
    S = NULL;
}

void studentsStruct::add(string n, int a, int b, int c)
{
    STUDENT *p, *q, *temp;
    p = q = S;
    temp = new STUDENT;
    temp->name = n;
    temp->quiz1 = a;
    temp->quiz2 = b;
    temp->quiz3 = c;

    while (p != NULL)
    {
        q = p;
        p = p->nxt;
    }
    if (p == S)
    {
        S = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        q->nxt = temp;
        temp->nxt = p;
    }
}

void studentsStruct::del(string n)
{
    STUDENT *p, *q;
    p = q = S;
    while (p != NULL && p->name != n)
    {
        q = p;
        p = p->nxt;
    }
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        cout << n << (" is not found.") << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
    else
    {
        if (p == S)
        {
            S = S->nxt;
        }
        else
        {
            q->nxt = p->nxt;
            delete (p);
            cout << n << (" is deleted from the student records") << endl;
        }
    }
}

void studentsStruct::update(string n)
{
    STUDENT *p, *q;
    p = q = S;
    int ua, ub, uc;

    while (p != NULL && p->name != n)
    {
        q = p;
        p = p->nxt;
    }
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        cout << ("Not Found") << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
    else
    {
        while (1)
        {
            cout << "Update Mode" << endl;
            cout << "Student : " << p->name << endl;
            cout << "Quiz 1 Grade: " << p->quiz1 << endl;
            cout << "Quiz 2 Grade: " << p->quiz2 << endl;
            cout << "Quiz 3 Grade: " << p->quiz3 << endl;

            switch (updatemenu())
            {
            case 1:
                cout << "Quiz 1 Grade: ";
                cin >> ua;
                p->quiz1 = ua;
                save();
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "Quiz 2 Grade: ";
                cin >> ub;
                p->quiz2 = ub;
                save();
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "Quiz 3 Grade: ";
                cin >> uc;
                p->quiz3 = uc;
                save();
                break;
            case 4:
                main();
                save();
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Select an option between 1 to 3" << endl;
                cout << "or select 4 to exit the Update Menu: " << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}

int updatemenu()
{
    int um;
    cout << "Update Menu" << endl;
    cout << "1.) Update Quiz 1 Grade" << endl;
    cout << "2.) Update Quiz 2 Grade" << endl;
    cout << "3.) Update Quiz 3 Grade" << endl;
    cout << "4.) Return to the Main Menu" << endl;
    cout << "Select an option between 1 to 3" << endl;
    cout << "or select 4 to exit the Update Menu: ";
    cin >> um;
    return (um);
}

void studentsStruct::display()
{
    STUDENT *p;
    int i = 1;
    p = S;
    float ave;
    string remarks;
    system("cls");
    cout << "No.\tName\tQuiz 1\tQuiz 2\tQuiz 3\tAverage\tRemarks\n";

    while (p != NULL)
    {
        ave = (p->quiz1 + p->quiz2 + p->quiz3) / 3.0;
        remarks = ave >= 75 ? "Passed" : "Failed";
        cout << i++ << ".)\t" << p->name << "\t" << p->quiz1 << "\t" << p->quiz2 << "\t" << p->quiz3 << "\t" << round2(ave) << "\t" << remarks << endl;
        p = p->nxt;
    }
    system("pause");
}

int menu()
{
    int op;
    cout << "Menu" << endl;
    cout << "1.) Insert" << endl;
    cout << "2.) Update" << endl;
    cout << "3.) Delete" << endl;
    cout << "4.) Display" << endl;
    cout << "5.) Exit" << endl;
    cout << "Select(1-5): ";
    cin >> op;
    return (op);
}

// Save the student data to "studentdb.txt" if available and create a file if needed
void studentsStruct::save()
{
    STUDENT *p;
    p = S;
    ofstream stuData;
    stuData.open("studentdb.txt");

    while (p != NULL)
    {
        stuData << p->name << " " << p->quiz1 << " " << p->quiz2 << " " << p->quiz3 << endl;
        p = p->nxt;
    }

    stuData.close();
}

// Check if the "studentdb.txt" is available and load the data as needed
void studentsStruct::retrieve()
{

    ifstream fp;
    string n;
    int ax, by, cz;

    fp.open("studentdb.txt");

    if (fp.peek() != std::ifstream::traits_type::eof())
    {
        while (fp >> n >> ax >> by >> cz)
        {
            add(n, ax, by, cz);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The file is available but contains no records" << endl;
    }

    fp.close();
}

// function to round the average and limit to 2 decimal points
float round2(float x)
{
    return trunc(x * 100.0) / 100.0;
}
```

And this is the error I am encountering (see screenshot below):

[image]

Comment: And when you used your debugger to investigate the reason for the error, including running your program step by step, one line at a time, until it errors out, what did you see, exactly?

Comment: I didn't really looked at the whole code but I think you're missing a [null terminator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-a-null-terminated-string-in-c-cplusplus)

Comment: Your program is invalid. You are not permitted to call `main`

Comment: *I have encountered no build errors.* -- That has no bearing on whether your program is logically correct.  If I asked you to write a program to add two numbers, but instead it subtracted two numbers, that program also builds with no errors, but is it correct?  No build errors only means that the program has no syntax errors, and the linker found all of the functions you're calling.  Nothing else.

Comment: *Please help check and advise when you have the chance* -- Debugging your own programs is part and parcel of learning how to write programs.  The error is not caused by a faulty compiler, build setting, or something external.  It is caused by one or more bugs in your program.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik no errors when debugged, and now the 'Debug > Start/Continue' option is disabled.  Not working as well when I press F8 (shortcut).

Comment: `if (fp.peek() != std::ifstream::traits_type::eof())` -- Explain why this unorthodox piece of code is used to simply read data from a file.  Hopefully you're not using [cargo cult programming techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Comment: @Wahalez I thought I had one at the end, as it is running and only breaking after the 3rd Insert.  I will check that.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie for ```if (fp.peek() != std::ifstream::traits_type::eof())``` I am checking if there's already an existing file, so that it will just open that file and continue inserting/deleting/updating.
Background as well is that I only started coding 3 months ago, self-studying, so that'll explain unorthodox commands.  Thank you.

Comment: @TedLyngmo please help me understand why main is not permitted, because I learned C with main being used, then moved to C++ once I got the hang of it, and always used main.  Happy to read a link you will provide.  Thanks.

Comment: g++ on ubuntu 20 -- enabling '[-Wpedantic]' will  cause a report "warning: ISO C++ forbids taking address of function ‘::main’ [-Wpedantic]", reminding you that you should not invoke main.   Perhaps you do not have enough other warnings enabled.

Comment: @JazzyJeffie -- C++ has `std::forward_list` and `std::list`.  There is no need to write your own linked list class.  Second, `typedef struct` is not needed in C++.  Last, there is `std::filesystem` available in C++17 and above.  Checking for file existence can be done using [filesystem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) and the `exists` function.

Comment: @2785528 I am running Code::Blocks on Windows 10, but also practice on Garuda Linux.  I don't copy files over, and instead copy just the code back-and-forth via email 'Draft' (saving it there, then picking it up when I am in another computer).  What does the G++ on ubuntu 20 mean?

Comment: Side note: I really think you should split the code into files for more readable and understandable code.

Comment: Thanks @PaulMcKenzie let me read the links you have posted and revisit my code.  Thanks for your time and support.

Comment: @Wahalez thanks for the suggestion.  As mentioned, I am still very new (3 months in) and practicing very early logic first via the books I read, & videos I watch (Caleb Curry) & tutorialspoint

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie any links/websites/books you can recommend to help add to my list of reading material?  I am going through C Programming as referred here: https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628

Comment: @JazzyJeffie You can read it in the C++ standard [`[basic.start.main]/6.9.3.1.3`](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#3.sentence-1) "_The function `main` shall not be used within a program._"